# Using JavaScript to create SVG vectors

Tags: javascript, variables, svg, vector

I am trying to find a way to create an SVG polyline where the 'x' and 'y' values for each point are defined as the values generated by a JavaScript file. These figures are based on a series of random variables with if/else conditions.

I have prepared the JavaScript file for plotting these points but I don't know the correct way to link the variable id's into the SVG script. Is this even possible and does anyone know how this it can be done?

Cheers.

Comment: I seem to get faster, better, and more answers when I [include just a little snippet of code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). probably because it is much easier for others to copy/paste/modify rather than writing an example from scratch, and programmers can more generally read the code to quickly see the problem regardless of what language in which the question was written.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
var svgns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
var svgDocument = evt.target.ownerDocument;
var shape = svgDocument.createElementNS(svgns, "circle");
shape.setAttributeNS(null, "cx", 25);
shape.setAttributeNS(null, "cy", 25);
shape.setAttributeNS(null, "r",  20);
shape.setAttributeNS(null, "fill", "green");
```

A great tutorial for create SVG objects, can be found [link](http://softwareas.com/ajaxjavascript-8-ways-to-create-graphics-on-the-fly/)

Answer (score 0):

A SVG is a document, not a script. A script is a piece of executable code, typically in Javascript.

First: Obtain the SVG object. For example, if your svg is embedded inside a webpage:

```
var svg = document.getElementById("yourSVGObject"); /* If <svg id="yourSVGObject"> */
```

You can create a new SVG object this way:

```
var svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
svg.setAttributeNS("width", "100%");
svg.setAttributeNS("height", "100%");
svg.setAttributeNS("viewBox", "0 0 200 200"); /* This is the SVG coordinate system: x, y, width, height */
document.body.appendChild(svg); /* To add the SVG object to the webpage. You could also add it inside a div, for example. */
```

To add a polyline to a SVG object:

```
var polyline = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "polyline");
polyline.style.fill = "none";
polyline.style.stroke = "#ff0000";
polyline.style.strokeWidth = "2px";
svg.appendChild(polyline);
```

To modify the points on the polyline, you need to modify them all at once. You must supply a string, not a set of points:

```
polyline.setAttributeNS(null, "points", "10,10 90,20 170,50");
```

Note that the polyline element only draws the lines. If you want to, say, put circles at each point, you have to add one circle for each of these points.

If you have stored your points on an array:

```
var polylinePoints = [];
var circles = []; /* Optional */
for(var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
    polylinePoints.push(points[i].x + ", " + points[i].y);
    var circle = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "circle");
    circle.setAttributeNS(null, "cx", points[i].x);
    circle.setAttributeNS(null, "cy", points[i].y);
    circle.setAttributeNS(null, "r", 8); /* This is the radius of the circle */
    circle.setAttributeNS(null, "class", "polylinePoint"); /* You can style individual shapes using CSS */
    circles.push(circle); /* Optional */
    svg.appendChild(circle);
}
polyline.setAttributeNS(null, "points", polylinePoints.join(" "));
```

You can store each circle on an array in case you need to modify or remove the circles later.

To remove an individual shape, simply call:

```
shape.remove(); /* e.g. circle[5].remove(); polyline.remove(); */
```

Example fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/locoluis/hkLprw23/

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll go through the tutorial but I think I know what I need to do from what you've described.